# Cross Page Posting with ASP.NET value not available on target page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to pass a value between two pages. However on my target page, the value is not found.

My source page includes the following code.

```
 Public ReadOnly Property SQLString() As String
```

Get
  Return "SELECT * FROM City"
  End Get
 End Property

On my target aspx page I have included the following directive:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/tools/SearchResults.aspx"%>
```

In the target page code behind I have included the following in the page load:

```
 Me.Master.Page.PreviousPage.SQLString
```

However, Visual studio complains that, SQLString is not a member of System.Web.Ui.page.

I must note I am useing master pages, and vaguely recall this causing an issue when accomplishing this in the past.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the page to whatever type it actually is.

```
CType(Me.Master.Page.PreviousPage, ActualPageType).SqlString
```

In the code behind of your source page you will have a class declaration like the following:

```
Public Class ActualPageType 
    Inherits Page
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to define a class as you suggested, however Visual Studio complains that ActualPageType is not defined, even thought I defined it on my source page. Any other ideas?

Comment: The class should already exists in your code behind. You should only have to look there to get the name.

Comment: The other option is to create an interface (say ISqlResult) with the SQLString property and put the code for that in your App_Code folder. Then just have the target page implement the interface. The cast will then be CType(Me.Master.Page.PreviousPage, ISqlResult).SqlString.